# OrientDB, how to retrieve previous record version

Tags: version-control, versioning, graph-databases, orientdb

I'm researching OrientDB in order to evaluate versioning capabilities of graph databases.

Each record in OrientDB has a @version property which increases every time a record is updated. This indicates support for versioning. I've set up a simple example (using OrientDB SQL) to test this:

```
create class Product
create property Product.name string
create property Product.price integer
insert into Product (name, price) values ('Fridge', 449)
update Product set price = 479 where name = 'Fridge'
select from Product
```

After executing the statements above, I get the following query result:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#14:0",
            "@version": 2,
            "@class": "Product",
            "name": "Fridge",
            "price": 479
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.031 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

In this database state - how can I retrieve a previous version (version 1 in this simple case) of my record? Is this possible through an OrientDB SQL statement and/or via the OrientDB Java API? If not - what's the purpose of the @version property then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of the `@version` property is to check if any update have been made between the time you fetched the object and when you updated it.

For instance if in your code you **fetch** a `product`, you **update** its properties, in the meanwhile the object **has changed** in the database (another piece of code has updated it), then you **save** it : you are trying to update the object with the **version 2**, but it has the **version 3** in database.

This can help you to prevent concurrent access to your database.

I don't know if the functionality you are looking for will be implemented in `OrientDB`. 
If you don't need it, then don't do it. If you really need this, you can do it yourself, maybe by creating a Product_old class and fill it with previous records on update.

Comment: You should ask a new question with more details about your problem, like maybe how you are doing your updates.